# angular animation in ionic3 stop working after receiving custom cordova plugin for android response to button press

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am developing a custom cordova plugin (Android for now) to be used with Ionic. The plugin add a listener to the WebView with this code:

```
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;//store this for later
        this.webView.getView().setOnKeyListener(this);//add listener
        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT); // send no result cause the result will be sent by the listener
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
```

Then I override the listener in this way:

```js
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            {
                try {
                    result.put("button", "button pressed");
                } catch (JSONException err) {
                }

            } 
            
            PluginResult pr = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result);
            pr.setKeepCallback(keepCallback);
            this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pr);
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

On the Ionic side I can see the that the plugin is sending back the result correctly but it seems to add some weird behaviour: when the event is received from ionic, my code need to start an animation (angular animation), the animation is started but it doesn't complete. It seems to be stuck. If I interact with the ui in any way after the event is received (for example if I just tap the screen everything start working again,) the app start responding again
The animation work perfectly if I trigger it in another way.

The animation is created in this way:

```js
 @Component({
...
  animations: [
    trigger('buttonAnimation', [
      state('normal', style({
        'transform': 'scale(1.0)'
      })),
      state('big', style({
        'transform': 'scale(1.2)',
      })),
      transition('* => *', animate('.1s ease'))
    ]),
  ]
})
```

UPDATE:

I applied the animation in the template file in this way

```
<button>
        <i (click)="onButtonPressed()" [@buttonAnimation]="buttonState" (@buttonAnimation.done)="onAnimationEnd()"></i>
      </button>
```

and the callback coming from the cordova plugin trigger the animation by setting the variable

```
enter code here
    this.buttonState = 'big';
```

then the animation is re-init with

```
   onAnimationEnd() {
    this.buttonState = 'normal'
  }
```

The cordova plugin is used in this way to start the animation:

```
cordova.plugins.buttonListener.listenButtonClick(data => {
      this.buttonState = 'big';
}, err => {
});
```

UPDATE ON SOLUTION

I was able to solve this using yazantahhan's proposed solution. I just had to call ngZone INSIDE the callback cause I need to trigger the change AFTER the event arrive.

```
cordova.plugins.buttonListener.listenButtonClick(data => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    do stuff;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add how you are triggering the animation?

Comment: Can you add also how the plugin callback is settings the variable buttonState?

Comment: yep, I updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you need to force the detectChanges, or run it inside the ngZone.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){} 

ngOnInit() {
  cordova.plugins.buttonListener.listenButtonClick(data => {
    this.buttonState = 'big';
    this.ref.detectChanges();    
  }, err => { });
}
```

Or using the ngZone:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){} 

ngOnInit() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    cordova.plugins.buttonListener.listenButtonClick(data => {
      this.buttonState = 'big';  
     }, err => { });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible. Question: I have never triggered the change detector manually, why should this be necessary in this situation?

Comment: As the change was done outside Angular. The callback was from Cordova so the change was outside Angular. So Angular needs to know that some thing was changed, so you call the detectChanges

Comment: This works, only thing to change: call ngZone.run inside the callback, cause the change should be triggered after the event arrive, not when setting the listener.